# List and minipage indent problem

Tags: lists, indentation

Some times I need to enclose a list of questions in a minipage to put a picture on the right. When the minipage starts with a list there is an indent problem, when there is somme text before it works fine. How to avoid this problem.

The third instance is the one I want to avoid: I want it looks like the first.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse,calc}

% Redefinir les etiquettes des listes
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
    %[flushleft,alwaysadjust] les options annulent le décalage vers la droite

% Défini les étiquettes des listes par défaut.
\setdefaultenum{\bf 1.}{a)}{\it i.)}{}

% Défini les étiquettes des itemize par défaut.
\setdefaultitem{$\bullet$}{$\circ$}{}{}

\setdefaultleftmargin{1.5em}{1.5em}{}{}{}{}

\newcounter{ex}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ListExos}{sO{0}}{%
    \setcounter{ex}{#2}
    \begin{list}
        % défini la forme de l'étiquette
        {\stepcounter{ex}{%
        \tikz[anchor=base, baseline]
            \node[RndBox,minimum width=20pt] {\theex} ;}}
        % défini les longueurs
        {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
         \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
         \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}{}
         %\setlength{\parsep}{2pt} % Espace entre deux paragraphes dans une liste
         %\setlength{\itemsep}{.5em} ne pas toucher car cela
         %\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt} influence les sous liste
         }%
        %\vspace{0.5em}
    }
    {\end{list}}

\tikzset{RndBox/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
    thick,
    fill=#1,
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw=#2,
    text=#2,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    minimum width=.6cm,
    minimum height=1.25em,
    text depth = 0ex,
    font = \bfseries\sffamily
    },
    RndBox/.default={gray!25 and black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ListExos}
\item \begin{compactenum}
\item bla
\item bla
\end{compactenum}
\end{ListExos}

\bigskip

\begin{ListExos}
\item \hspace{-20pt}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-4cm}
\raggedrigth% ne pas commencer par une liste directement
\hspace{20pt} Some text before the first question.

\begin{compactenum}
\item bla
\item bla
\end{compactenum}
\end{minipage}
\end{ListExos}

\bigskip

How make it work without some text before the first question.

\begin{ListExos}
\item \hspace{-20pt}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-4cm}
\raggedrigth% ne pas commencer par une liste directement
\hspace{20pt}\begin{compactenum}
\item bla
\item bla
\end{compactenum}
\end{minipage}
\end{ListExos}


\verb+\setlength\itemindent{-20pt}+ doesn't for several lines

\bigskip

\begin{ListExos}
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\raggedright% ne pas commencer par une liste directement

\begin{compactenum}

\item Reproduire une figure du même type que celle ci-contre.

\setlength\itemindent{-20pt}

\item Contruire deux points $B$ et $C$ tels que C soit inscrit dans le triangle $ABC$.

Proposer plusieurs solutions.
\end{compactenum}
\end{minipage}
\end{ListExos}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear.  Of the three instances in the diagram at the top of your question, which of the 3 are "good" and which are "bad"?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The third instance is the one I want to avoid.

Comment: Please note that the list spacings are different in `minipage` environments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't understand.

Comment: is the indentation on the lines after the first in the multi-line example what you want?  do the boxed numbers ever increase to more than one digit, and if so, does the width of the box change?

Comment: Tikz box can go up to 99 without changing `minimum width=20pt`, its enough for a list of exercises ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I want `que` goes under `Construire`.

Comment: where do you want `même` to begin?  under `Reproduire` as shown, or also to the same indentation as `Construire`?

Comment: Don't worry I just found a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things I would do differently, but here is a possible work around for your last environment:

```
\begin{ListExos}
  \item %\hspace{-20pt}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-4cm}
      %\hspace{20pt}%  
      \raggedright% ne pas commencer par une liste directement
      \begin{compactenum}%%
        \item bla
        \setlength\itemindent{-20pt}
        \item bla
      \end{compactenum}
    \end{minipage}
\end{ListExos}
```

[image]

Part of your problem is using the `\hspace{20pt}`.  You're creating a box which will cause the list environment to add vertical space.  Instead, what I've done is reset the `\itemindent` after the item in your list.

Comment: Doesn't work for several lines case. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `item` in the `minipage` solves the problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse,calc}

% Redefinir les etiquettes des listes
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
    %[flushleft,alwaysadjust] les options annulent le décalage vers la droite

% Défini les étiquettes des listes par défaut.
\setdefaultenum{\bf 1.}{a)}{\it i.)}{}

% Défini les étiquettes des itemize par défaut.
\setdefaultitem{$\bullet$}{$\circ$}{}{}

\setdefaultleftmargin{1.5em}{1.5em}{}{}{}{}

\newcounter{ex}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ListExos}{sO{0}}{%
    \setcounter{ex}{#2}
    \begin{list}
        % défini la forme de l'étiquette
        {\stepcounter{ex}{%
        \tikz[anchor=base, baseline]
            \node[RndBox,minimum width=20pt] {\theex} ;}}
        % défini les longueurs
        {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
         \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
         \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}{}
         %\setlength{\parsep}{2pt} % Espace entre deux paragraphes dans une liste
         %\setlength{\itemsep}{.5em} ne pas toucher car cela
         %\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt} influence les sous liste
         }%
        %\vspace{0.5em}
    }
    {\end{list}}

\tikzset{RndBox/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
    thick,
    fill=#1,
    inner sep=0pt,
    draw=#2,
    text=#2,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    minimum width=.6cm,
    minimum height=1.25em,
    text depth = 0ex,
    font = \bfseries\sffamily
    },
    RndBox/.default={gray!25 and black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{ListExos}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\raggedright% ne pas commencer par une liste directement
\item \begin{compactenum}

\item Reproduire une figure du même type que celle ci-contre.

\item Contruire deux points $B$ et $C$ tels que C soit inscrit dans le triangle $ABC$.

Proposer plusieurs solutions.
\end{compactenum}
\end{minipage}
\end{ListExos}

\end{document}
```